# Fix maven plugins while offline

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My offline maven installation has stopped working for some reason.  It no longer seems to recognize any plugins including install and dependency.

For instance if I enter: "mvn install:help" and "I get No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project..."

I have searched and most solutions say things like "delete your local repository and maven will download what it needs."  That won't work because my development environment is not connected to the internet.  I can download files on a different machine and then transfer what I need, but I can't seem to get maven to recognize it.  The error messages indicate that it is looking in the local repository and I can verify that the files are there but yet it doesn't find them.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you provide more logs from your executions?

Comment: Provide as much relevant information as possible so we can better help you, ex OS, version etc

Comment: This is a Windows 10 installation.  The Maven Version is 3.0.5.  The full text of the error lines is too long to fit in a comment, but it starts like this:
'[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.mortbay.jetty, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\oliver.harris\.m2\repository), plugins (file:C:\Users\oliver.harris\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins), thirdpartyjars (file:C:\Users\oliver.harris\.m2\repository\thirdpartyjars), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] '

Comment: The local repository has the maven-install-plugin in the directory where it should be, and yet maven claims it can't find it.